# Resolving strongly-typing logical conflict in an MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On my View I'd like to loop through a DataTable using methods such as Rows and Columns so that I can dynamically populate HTML tables. To that end I strongly-typed my Razor View to System.Data.DataTable.

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
```

But in order to handle the data--which I'm pulling from SQL Server using straight ADO.NET--I built an actual Model Class that returns that very DataTable that I'd like to loop through on the View.

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public Class DimensionY
    {
        public DataTable getDimMembers(string tableName)
        {
            //GET DATA FROM SQL AND PUT IT ONTO someDataTable
            return someDataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

My HomeController then calls this DimensionY Model Class shown above and then passes a DataTable object to the View:

```
public ActionResult Index (string tableName)
{
    DimensionY newMemSet = new DimensionY();
    newMemSet.getDimMembers(tableName);

    return View(newMemSet);
}
```

So if I strongly-type the View to my own model, I seem to loose the Rows and Columns methods that System.Data.DataTable gives me. But if I strongly-type the View to the actual Model, the compiler tells me:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.DimensionY', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

How could I strongly type a View to my own model and at the same type use the DataTable type methods?

Answer (score 1):

The model has to match the object you pass down to the view.

Change it to `@model MyProject.Models.DimensionY`